# PHP unexpected 'public'

Tags: php

I have this error on my PHP application

```
(syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) ln6)
```

And I haven't found the solution

```php
    class User
{
    public const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active';
    public const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive';

    public function __construct(public string $username, public string $status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? This code requires a minimum of PHP 8.0.

Comment: Remove visibility of parameters passed to the construct, change `public string` to `string`.

Answer (score -1):

There should not be any access modifier like public, private, or protected in parameters. Since parameters for any functions are the inputs and setting public, private, or protected never makes any sense.

```
<?php
    class User
    {
        public const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active';
        public const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive';
    
        public function __construct( string $username,  string $status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much the error disappears. It is absurd this example comes from a school course.